# Django extras() - Logic/algorithm

Tags: python, sql, django, algorithm, django-rest-framework

I have a that looks like this:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile, related_name='posts')

    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, null = True)
```

That has two models related to it:

```
class Comments(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile, related_name='author')
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='posts')


class Likes(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile, related_name='liker')
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='post' )
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created',)
```

Now, the logic is basically to calculate the amount of likes + the amount of comments over decayed over time:

```
likes + comments / now() - post.created
```

I've created the sql version of this logic, now using django extra I created:

```
s = Post.objects.extras(select={'post':'logic here...... WHERE id = %d} % **MISSING PIECE THAT ALLOWS ME TO ITERATE OVER THE POST OBJECTS**)
```

Can anyone help me out on what the missing piece can be? I tried using Post.objects.all().id, which doesn't work because it's a queryset.

Any help is appreciated, comments for more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allow me to change the related names to something that would make more sense

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile, related_name='posts')

class Comments(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile, related_name='comments')
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='comments')

class Likes(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile, related_name='likes')
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='likes' )
```

Now you can do

```
post = Post.objects.get(pk=1)
output = ( post.likes.all().count() + post.comments.all().count() ) / ( now() - post.created )
```

**UPDATE**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def output(self):
        return ( self.likes.all().count() + self.comments.all().count() ) / (datetime.datetime.now() - self.created_at).total_seconds()

thelist = sorted(Post.objects.all(), key: lambda p : p.output)
```

As far as I know, you can't sort the list on something that's not directly database related. So get the information as you want it, and sort it in Python.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I need to order all post by "output" in this case, which is why I just tried using extras, because of "order_by". How do you think I can go about that? this is for django-rest framework as well.

Comment: sick! exactly what I wanted!